# Create unique id based on date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In MongoDb the automatically assigned id (ObjectId) for new documents is unique and contains within itself the timestamp of its creation.

Without using any library (other than built-in libs of Python), how can I create this type of concise unique ids that also somehow holds its timestamp of creation?

Comment: Concatenation of some unique data and the timestamp? For example, user_id + some other info + timestamp of creation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python

Comment: Or do you also mean creation of timestamp without using any library

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a multithreaded or multi-machine scenario, all bets are off and you should not rely on any "extra level of unique assurance" if using timestamp only. Read more from [this excellent answer from deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883012/3594865).

Similar to above answers, another option is to concatenate timestamp and uuid:

```
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4

eventid = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m-%d%H-%M%S-') + str(uuid4())
eventid
>>> '201902-0309-0347-3de72c98-4004-45ab-980f-658ab800ec5d'
```

`eventid` contains 56 characters which may or may not be an issue for you. However, it holds timestamp of creation and is sortable all of which could be advantageous in a database allowing you to query `eventid`s between two timestamps, say.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to create current timestamp:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Now you can concatenate that with anything you want.

If you want to add microseconds to make sure it is unique just add `%f` to the end:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

Comment: I like the idea of being able to have the timestamp human readable +1! I think that adding the microseconds is a must though to add an extra level of unique assurance.

Answer (score 7):

Using an epoch timestamp with a sufficient amount of precision might just be enough for you. Combine this with a simple user id and you'll have yourself a unique ID with a timestamp embedded into it:

```
import time
epoch = time.time()
user_id = 42 # this could be incremental or even a uuid
unique_id = "%s_%d" % (user_id, epoch)
```

`unique_id` will now have a value similar to `42_1526466157`. You can take this value and split it by the `_` character - now you have the original epoch of creation time (1526466157).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UUID](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid#uuid.uuid4), built in to the standard library. Specifically you can use a `uuid4` just for a little extra security because it doesn't encode the computer's network address.

```
import uuid

print(uuid.uuid4()) #56d36372-b5ec-4321-93b8-939ee7d780aa
```

Comment: Where is the timestamp here? Please take another look at the OP's requirements - they need an id based on time

Comment: Is it possible to extract the timestamp from the id generated with this method?